# Eclipse not running on start up, showing wrong password error

Tags: java, android, eclipse

The .log file shows this:-

```
!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-07-04 15:50:51.019
!MESSAGE parseSdkContent failed
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.sdk.ProjectState.needs(ProjectState.java:466)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.sdk.Sdk$1.onProjectOpened(Sdk.java:1125)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.sdk.Sdk$1.projectOpenedWithWorkspace(Sdk.java:1092)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.resources.manager.GlobalProjectMonitor.addProjectListener(GlobalProjectMonitor.java:427)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.sdk.Sdk.<init>(Sdk.java:928)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.sdk.Sdk.loadSdk(Sdk.java:289)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.AdtPlugin$7.run(AdtPlugin.java:1415)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

Please help I am new to developing apps and cant find a solution to this.
VERSION:- eclipse juno

Comment: Are you running a clean ADT installation?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like something in your workspace is broken. Start eclipse in a new workspace, create a new project, and copy the files you need from the broken one.

Comment: Yeah.  Since it will be hard to start eclipse so that you can change the WS, just delete (or move it) from the file system.  By default it is in your home directory and is called "workspace".